# Facebook Python SDK - Upload image in Event Create

Tags: python, facebook, api, events

How do I upload image when creating the event on graph api?
Example:

```
user.facebook.put_object("me", "events", name="test", start_time=start_date, end_time=end_date, picture=image)
```

I've tried:

```
 image = 'C:\\Path\\to\\image.jpg' #and
 image = open('C:\\Path\\to\\image.jpg', 'a') #and
 image = open('C:\\Path\\to\\image.jpg', 'a').read() #and
```

None worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs on github: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
tags = json.dumps([{'x':50, 'y':50, tag_uid:12345}, {'x':10, 'y':60, tag_text:'a turtle'}])
graph.put_photo(open('img.jpg'), 'Look at this cool photo!', album_id_or_None, tags=tags)
```